# Weka Apriori class documentation

Tags: java, api, weka, javadoc

Where can I find more information on how exactly the following method works
and what it actually does? I found the single line of the documentation leaves a bit to be desired:

**Class weka.associations.Apriori**

```
public void buildAssociations(Instances instances) throws Exception
Method that generates all large itemsets with a minimum support, and from these all association rules with a minimum confidence.
```

Comment: Do you have access to the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at *all* the documentation, not only the method documentation tooltip in your IDE. You are missing out on a *lot* of the documentation.

Weka comes with a **whole book**, that will give you plenty of detail.

The [Apriori class documentation](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/associations/Apriori.html) also contains much more than that single line you quoted. You failed to access the JavaDoc class documentation; it's not the documentation that "leaves a bit to be desired", is it? It points to two publication giving the details on the algorithm.